# can I do a regex search/replace in vs.net?

Tags: visual-studio, regex

In vs.net, I want to search for all occurances of

[someWord]

in my .sql file, and replace it with

[SomeWord]

Is this possible?  (notice the uppercasing of the first character in the result)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do Regex searches/Replaces in vs.net, just make sure to check the box in the dialog. The regex syntax is different from the Perl/.Net one though. Pay attention to the differences in syntax.

There's some reference here:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000633.html

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a certain word:-

```
s/\[someWord\]/[SomeWord]/
```

But it might just be better to use a replace function

If it's anything in square brackets.

```
s/\[[a-zA-Z]+\]/[\u\1]/
```

Comment: it said argument is missing in \ escape sequence ? (using vs.net replace using regex)

Comment: /me doesn't know vs.net well enough to give you something specific fo ti - I just know that's a valid PCRE.

Which did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you might open that sql file externally is some editor like notepad++ and replace the stuff accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/searcheraddin.aspx), this is VS Addin for regex search and replace found on **CodeProject**. Be warned that the code was for VS 2003, but can be recompiled I'm sure for later versions of VS.NET.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.